# Arduino PWM 1kHz and 10-bit resolution

Tags: pwm

As the title says, I need 1khz frequency signal with 10-bit resolution. But I am not good with uControllers and complicated programming.

I need a simple code for this task.

I tried using this [Interactive PWM](https://www.arduinoslovakia.eu/blog/2017/7/16-bitove-rozlisenie-pwm-pre-arduino?lang=en) from arduinoslovakia.eu but I dont know what the frequency is at 10-bit resolution and how to set frequency in this code.

Comment: Are you talking about a square wave? In what way would it have 10-bit resolution? Either it is 1 kHz or not, yes? Are you talking about an error factor? Like, 1 kHz +/- 5% ?

Comment: @NickGammon The "10-bit resolution" will refer to the resolution of the duty cycle parameter. i.e., a duty cycle between 0 and 1023 instead of the normal 0 to 255.

Comment: Perhaps but the rather brief question does not mention duty cycles.

Comment: @NickGammon No, but it *does* mention PWM, and PWM has a duty cycle (which is what makes it PWM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are talking about using the 16-bit timer, which is Timer 1 on the Uno.

Assuming you are using a Uno this code will do it:

```c++
// Clock frequency divided by 1 kHz frequency desired
const long timer1_OCR1A_Setting = F_CPU / 1000;

const byte outputPin = 10;  // Timer 1 "B" output: OC1B

void setup() 
 {
  pinMode (outputPin, OUTPUT);

  // set up Timer 1
  // Fast PWM top at OCR1A
  TCCR1A = bit (WGM10) | bit (WGM11) | bit (COM1B1); // fast PWM, clear OC1B on compare
  TCCR1B = bit (WGM12) | bit (WGM13) | bit (CS10);   // fast PWM, no prescaler
  OCR1A =  timer1_OCR1A_Setting - 1;                 // zero relative
  OCR1B =  (timer1_OCR1A_Setting / 2) - 1;           // 50 % duty cycle
  }  // end of setup

void loop()
  {
  }
```

You can change the 1000 in the calculation for timer1_OCR1A_Setting, within reason, to get other frequencies.

See [my page about timers](http://www.gammon.com.au/timers) for more background information.

Comment: On a 16Mhz Arduino you'd get around 14 bits of resolution, using this code. It is however impossible to get exactly 14-bit (or 10-bit) of resolution without changing the frequency (to around 0.9765kHz).

Comment: To explain that comment, OCR1A would be set to 16000 using the above code, and that is `log(16000)/log(2)` bits, namely 13.97 bits roughly. Therefore your duty cycle (OCR1B) could be in the range 0 to 15999 giving at least 10 bits of resolution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.